# Query with multiple EXISTS returing too many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exists

Original table has 1466303 records in it, I have inserted 1108441 of those records in to a separate table. What I would like to know is what data is left over? So I have made a query using multiple exists to find the data that was left:

```
SELECT SG_customer,
       PHONE,
       SG_Name,
       SG_Secondary_Address,
       SG_Primary_Address,
       SG_City,
       SG_State,
       SG_Zip,
       SG_Email
FROM   FMJ_DB_VPI_EXPANDED_DATA X
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   FMJScore
                   WHERE  SGID = X.SG_Customer
                          AND Phone = X.Phone
                          AND Name = X.SG_Name
                          AND SecondAddress = X.SG_Secondary_Address
                          AND Address = X.SG_Primary_Address
                          AND City = X.SG_City
                          AND State = X.SG_State
                          AND Zip = X.SG_Zip
                          AND Email = X.SG_Email)
```

Running this returns back 144391 records, there should be a difference of 357862, I don't understand why its returning back so many records.

Comment: My first guess is that some of the fields are `NULL`, so no match is found.

Comment: Yes that is true some are null, is there a way to do this with NULL data?

Comment: select * from t1 minus select * from t2; (see MINUS operator)

Comment: if you use MINUS take into consideration that MINUS eliminates dublicates, so the result may still contain fewer rows

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Use `EXCEPT` for SQL Server (instead of `MINUS`)

Comment: MSSQL minus did not work

Comment: @TimMorford . . . I would expect `minus` to work for this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want null to be treated equal to null, I also assume that '' is not used as a value, if it is replace it with something that does not normally occur:

```
SELECT SG_customer,
   PHONE,
   SG_Name,
   SG_Secondary_Address,
   SG_Primary_Address,
   SG_City,
   SG_State,
   SG_Zip,
   SG_Email
FROM   FMJ_DB_VPI_EXPANDED_DATA X
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   FMJScore
               WHERE  coalesce(SGID,'') = coalesce(X.SG_Customer,'')
                      AND coalesce(Phone,'') = coalesce(X.Phone,'')
                      AND coalesce(Name,'') = coalesce(X.SG_Name,'')
                      AND coalesce(SecondAddress,'') = coalesce(X.SG_Secondary_Address,'')
                      AND coalesce(Address,'') = coalesce(X.SG_Primary_Address,'')
                      AND coalesce(City,'') = coalesce(X.SG_City,'')
                      AND coalesce(State,'') = coalesce(X.SG_State,'')
                      AND coalesce(Zip,'') = coalesce(X.SG_Zip,'')
                      AND coalesce(Email,'') = coalesce(X.SG_Email,''))
```

The optimizer might not be able to use indexes efficiently due to the function call